# Low Title: unable to get custom field to output

Tags: custom-fields, low

I'm trying to get a custom field to output using Low Title on an EE5 site and I'm not able to get it working. I'm trying this:

```
{exp:low_title:entry entry_id="122" custom_field="{field_short_name}"}
```

Also this:

```
{exp:low_title:entry url_title="main" custom_field="{field_short_name}" channel="channel_name"}
```

...where "main" is the URL title of the entry I want. But I keep just getting the actual title of the entry instead of the custom field.

Any idea what I'm missing? When I set "show_error" to yes, I get an error that the custom field is not found.

Answer (score 0):

**custom_field** should have a short name of the custom field to return instead of the title. Based on your code, it looks like you trying to get this short name from some variable *{field_short_name}*. Is it correct?

In this case, the issue could be in parsing order. Mean that when the parser executed low_title:entry tag your variable is not processed yet and parameter don't have a correct fieldname.  Needs to see a whole code for this.

p.s. if field_short_name is not variable but the real short name(happened) -  remove **{ }**